# dirtycow exploit without gcc

Tags: linux, gcc

I found many vulnerabilities but almost all of them require `gcc` which is not available on most of my target machines.

I was wondering if it's possible to run dirtycow without `gcc` installed or what is the alternative to do it?

Comment: This question is just a "how do I compile a piece of software on machine A, and run it on machine B". Relation to infosec is incidental.

Answer (score 1):

The [DirtyCOW PoC page](https://github.com/dirtycow/dirtycow.github.io/wiki/PoCs) contains a list of proof of concept exploits, including several that do not require GCC. There is one written in Go and even one which requires only an assembler. You can also analyze how the exploit works and implement it yourself in whatever language is available to you.

Comment: cc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

I will try ruby

Comment: @Bornvs.Me Oh so I guess the Ruby one was just a compiler wrapper. [Yeah](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/7476/files/046d3ea263e5f39f3ab70a1b5491ee472d57ee5f#diff-d671da4eddd9ce4e72dfabd94f3614caR163).

Comment: Yes I saw it, its for metasploit, I ahve access to the machine already, I dont know what metasploit can help me do

Comment: @Bornvs.Me I removed the mention of Ruby. You can use Go, or implement it yourself.

Comment: is go available out of the box? how can I implement it myself? any tuts?

Comment: @Bornvs.Me I doubt there are any tutorials. First, pick a language you have that lets you call syscalls directly (even Python can do that with the right libraries). Read the other PoCs to see how the exploit is implemented, and re-implement it yourself. It's a necessary skill to have for exploitation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87794/discussion-between-born-vs-me-and-forest).

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm missing something... just compile it on another machine and copy it over? Although if you dont have access to a system with a compatible compiler then i suppose THAT is your problem. You do not strictly need gcc on the target.

Comment: DO I need to compile with another identical machine?

Comment: I did compile with anothe rlinux (higher version) but It displays an error

Comment: Is there any list of precompiled dirtycow?